# Get size of SWT Label with word wrap

Tags: label, swt, size, word-wrap

Is there a way to get the exact size computed by a label before laying it out.

In other words, let us say there is a label with a really long sentence:

> Hi how are you doing, my name is bond, I have no name, I live in London, but yet the world is my Home. I am here to play and enjoy.

This is a single line. however if the window is not large enough, then the label wraps into two lines.

I want to find out the final height that it will take up, before laying it out (this is so that I can adjust the font size accordingly so that it displays in a single line).

However if I do `label.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT)` it only returns the size that it needs without wrapping.

If there is a way to do it that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fist of all the `Label` must be created with the `SWT.WRAP` style. Otherwise it will never wrap its text.

Then you need to tell `computeSize` what width the label should have. Otherwise `computeSize` doesn't know where to wrap and computes the size for the unwrapped text.

If you specify the desired width of the label, `computeSize` will return the neccesary height.

For example

```java
Label label = new Label( shell, SWT.WRAP );
label.setText( "Snippets are minimal stand-alone programs that demonstrate specific techniques or functionality." );
Point size = label.computeSize( 200, SWT.DEFAULT );
System.out.println( size );  // Point {202, 47}
```

The returned `size` is a  `Point` whose `x` field is (almost) the desired width and the `y` field denotes the necessary height to display the wrapped text.

On my system, the size is { 202, 47 } (the text spans two lines) but this may vary depending on the platform and font size.

Comment: I dont know if I am doing something wrong, but when I try this with label.computeSize(10, SWT.DEFAULT) or label.computeSize(100, SWT.DEFAULT) doesn't seem to change anything. It keeps saying that I only need X height where X is the height required to display a single line.

Comment: I've added an example to my answer, HTH.

Comment: ah I see, I dont think I used SWT.WRAP, I will check it out

Comment: Yes, `SWT.WRAP` must be specified, otherwise the label will never wrap (see the edited answer).

Comment: Thank you so much! I just got the opportunity to try it out and it worked. It was the SWT.WRAP that did it. WIthout it like you said it was assuming it to be a single line, although in the front end it was technically wrapping. :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Rudiger Herrmann's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33708309/2691625).
I have done it previously for my purpose. But it was dependent on OS. I have adjusted size of the font to make label in a line in a Grid. Please find comments in code.

```java
parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
label = new Label( parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP );
label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
label.setTouchEnabled(true);
label.setToolTipText("LABEL");
label.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_MAGENTA));
label.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_GREEN));
label.setText( "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmermers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites." );
Point parentCompositeSize = parent.getShell().getSize();
System.out.println(parentCompositeSize);
// parentCompositeSize.x is width of parent window (Shell) width, if you have your desired width of (window / Composite) then you can give it direct in int
// Calculation of number of lines with default font ::
// Warning:: Calculations have some assumption as below.
//1. Spacing between two lines will be 1 unit.
//2. My Layout used is GRID Layout.
Point estimatedLabelSize = label.computeSize( parentCompositeSize.x, SWT.DEFAULT );
System.out.println( "Estimated Label Height " + estimatedLabelSize.y);  
FontData[] fD = label.getFont().getFontData();
int defaultFontSize = fD[0].getHeight(); //Font Height is 11 in my case.
defaultFontSize += 1; //1 is spacing between two lines, According to assumption
System.out.println(defaultFontSize + "default size");
int lines = estimatedLabelSize.y / defaultFontSize;
System.out.println("Default fonts will print " + lines + " lines" );
int suggestedFontSize = defaultFontSize / lines;
System.out.println(suggestedFontSize +" suggested size ");

fD[0].setHeight(suggestedFontSize);
final Font newFont = new Font(parent.getDisplay(), fD);
label.setFont(newFont);
label.addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener() {

    @Override
    public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e) {
        newFont.dispose();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank Ardeshana Milan for this fantastic answer. SWT.WRAP did the trick. Since Rudiger was first to suggest it, I accept the answer, however I am equally thankful to you for trying to help me out. Have a great day.

Comment: Yes it must be like that only :). Thanks